# C# LocalReport change textbox location

Tags: c#, localreport

How can I change position in LocalReport of any object. Like TextBox or Image and so on. For example try to change Left coordinate.
I was try this way:

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", "ValueFromCode"));
report.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

but i can't establish a link between reportParameters and location of element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions to dynamically assign values to properties. For instance, if you open a `TextBox` properties, go to *Alignment*, and then click on *Fx* - located to the right of the Left padding field for instance - the expression editor will open.

There, you can select some report parameter like the `ReportParameter1` from your example. This would be translated into the following .rdlc code inside the `Style` tag of the corresponding `TextBox`:

```
<PaddingLeft>=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value</PaddingLeft>
```

Your `ValueFromCode` may be something like `10pt`, or some numeric value instead, to which you may then append the units, for instance:

```
<PaddingLeft>=Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value &amp; "pt"</PaddingLeft>
```

Now, this example is for padding, which you can edit using the designed. I haven't tried it, but in order to set the location dynamically you may be able to do the same for the `Top` and `Left` properties of the `TextBox` (or the desired element), by manually editing the `.rdlc` file. Give it a try.

Comment: I was try your method. It is work only for PaddingLeft, but for Left don't.